# How to make (patient id) forgein key in table of bill?

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to create three tables by using website suport compiler any code but I have a problem in the table of the bill. 
When I run it I get to error show me it is near in foreign key

[image]

These are codes of three tables

```
CREATE TABLE patient (
Patient Id    (5) Primary key,
Name   Varchar (20) Not null , 
Age    Int  Not null ,
Weight Int Not null , 
Gender Varchar (10) Not null,
Address Varchar (50) Not null , 
Disease Varchar (20) Not null
);

CREATE TABLE doctors (
DoctorId Varchar (5) Primary key,
Doctorname Varchar (15) Not null,
Dept Varchar (15) Not null
);


CREATE TABLE bill (
Bill_no Varchar (50) Primary key,
Patient_Id Varchar (5) Foreign key,,
doctor_charge Int Not null,
patient_type Varchar (10) null,
no_of_days Int null,
lab_charge Int null,
bill Int Not null
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Patient Table**

```
 CREATE TABLE patient
  (
     patient_id VARCHAR (5) PRIMARY KEY,
     name       VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
     age        INT NOT NULL,
     weight     INT NOT NULL,
     gender     VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
     address    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
     disease    VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
  );
```

Errors

- No data type has been assigned in Patient id column (`Patient Id (5)
  Primary key`)
- Patient id column name contains spaces. You need to
  enclose the column name in double quotes or replace space with something else
  (ex: `_`). It's not recommended to use spaces.

A column name with space

```
CREATE TABLE tablename ("column name" datatype);
```

**Doctors Table**

```
CREATE TABLE doctors
  (
     doctorid   VARCHAR (5) PRIMARY KEY,
     doctorname VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
     dept       VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL
  );
```

**Bill Table**

```
CREATE TABLE bill
  (
     bill_no       VARCHAR (50) PRIMARY KEY,
     patient_id    VARCHAR (5),
     doctor_charge INT NOT NULL,
     patient_type  VARCHAR (10) NULL,
     no_of_days    INT NULL,
     lab_charge    INT NULL,
     bill          INT NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY (patient_id) REFERENCES patient(patient_id)
  );
```

Errors

- The way you have assigned foreign key is wrong. Please refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) and [this article](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php) for more information. (`Patient_Id Varchar (5) Foreign key,,`)
- There are two commans in the `Patient_Id` column (`Patient_Id Varchar (5) Foreign key,,`)

Comment: How to write code as you .  CREATE TABLE bill 
( Bill_no Varchar (50) Primary key, 
Patient_Id Varchar (5),
doctor_charge Int Not null,
patient_type Varchar (10) null, 
no_of_days Int null, 
lab_charge Int null, 
bill Int Not null,
CONSTRAINT fk_patient_id
FOREIGN KEY (Patient_Id)
REFERENCES  patient(Patient_Id) 
);

Comment: What do you mean..? Are you asking about the formatting or something else..? BTW, you can check these code using [this website](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bad18/4/0).

Comment: You commit at my post but I want to write code as you

Comment: You're talking about formatting. :) That's easy actually. Check these articles: [link1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/6327676), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [link4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). If you want to format your SQL query, you can use [this site](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) to do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the 'Foreign Key' from the table creation script.
2. Add this to your SQL script:

```
ALTER TABLE [Bill]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Bill_Patient] FOREIGN KEY([Patient_Id])
REFERENCES [Patient] ([Patient_Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [Bill] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Bill_Patient]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide reference of the table for which you want to use the reference key. 
For example, you have table Persons which has Primary key PersonID, in that case if you want to use that as foreign key in another table, lets say Orders.
In Oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
OrderID numeric(10) not null,
OrderNumber numeric(10) not null,
PersonID numeric(10) not null,
CONSTRAINT fk_person_id
FOREIGN KEY (PersonID )
REFERENCES Persons(PersonID )

Your Case : 
CREATE TABLE bill 
( Bill_no Varchar (50) Primary key, 
Patient_Id Varchar (5),
doctor_charge Int Not null,
patient_type Varchar (10) null, 
no_of_days Int null, 
lab_charge Int null, 
bill Int Not null,
CONSTRAINT fk_patient_id
FOREIGN KEY (Patient_Id)
REFERENCES  patient(Patient_Id) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The words `FOREIGN KEY` are only needed for introducing the name of the FK constraint. Since your other constraints are not named, you might as well skip that part and go straight to `REFERENCES`.

If you specify a foreign key constraint as part of the column definition, you can omit the datatype to allow it to inherit from its parent at the time of creation, which I think is good practice as the types will automatically match.

We use [`VARCHAR2`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-DF7E10FC-A461-4325-A295-3FD4D150809E) in Oracle, not `VARCHAR`.

You don't need to specify `NULL` for columns that are allowed to be null.

I am not sure a 5-character string is a good datatype for a unique ID. How will you generate the values? Normally an auto-incrementing sequence number simplifies this.

```
create table doctors
( doctorid       varchar2(5) primary key
, doctorname     varchar2(15) not null
, dept           varchar2(15) not null );

create table patients
( patient_id     varchar2(5) primary key
, name           varchar2(20) not null
, age            integer not null
, weight         integer not null
, gender         varchar2(10) not null
, address        varchar2(50) not null
, disease        varchar2(20) not null );

create table bills
( bill_no        varchar2(50) primary key
, patient_id     references patients  -- Allow datatype to inherit from parent
, patient_type   varchar2(10)
, no_of_days     integer
, lab_charge     integer
, bill           integer not null );
```